# Are Vec<T> stored with unused space in ink?

Tags: ink, storage, vec

I'm using a [`Vec<T>`](https://docs.rs/ink_prelude/4.0.1/ink_prelude/vec/struct.Vec.html) in `ink!`. When allocating elements to the vec, the underlying array may be resized to provide a constant amortised push complexity of O(1). This means that sometimes the vec has unused space (e.g. 5 items in the vec but the underlying array has length 8 with 3 null elements).

Does the vec get stored with or without the unused space in the smart contract?

I am currently considering calling [`shrink_to_fit()`](https://docs.rs/ink_prelude/4.0.1/ink_prelude/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.shrink_to_fit) before saving the vec in smart contract storage in order to save space. However, I'm hoping `ink!` does this automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Values written to the contract storage in ink! are SCALE encoded.
That means that no matter the capacity of the vector, the encoded value only includes what is in the `vec`.

Consider this:

When

```
let mut vec1 = Vec::new();
for _ in 0..5 {
   vec1.push(1);
}

let mut vec2 = Vec::new();
for _ in 0..5 {
   vec2.push(1);
}
vec2.shrink_to_fit();
```

Then

```
assert_eq!(vec1.encode(), vec2.encode())
```

Also when

```
let mut vec1 = Vec::with_capacity(10);
vec1.push(10);

let vec2 = vec![10];
```

Then

```
assert_eq!(vec1.encode(), vec2.encode());
```